# What is the difference of F5 to Ctrl+F5 in matter of load times?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

I have the following Code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="colorfield"></div>
        <script>
            function insertElement(color,nr){
                var html = document.getElementById("colorfield").innerHTML;
                html += "<span style='background-color: "+color+";'>"+nr+"</span>";
                if(nr % 10 == 0) html += "<br>";
                document.getElementById("colorfield").innerHTML = html;
            }

            function getColor(nr){
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                      var response = this.responseText; 
                      color = JSON.parse(response).colors[0].value;
                      insertElement(color,nr);
                  }
                };
                xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.noopschallenge.com/hexbot", true);
                xhttp.send(); 
            }
            for(i=1;i<=100;i++){
                getColor(i)
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This just prints the number of the request with a random background-color which comes from https://api.noopschallenge.com/hexbot.

If i (re)load the page normally (F5), the elements will be printed in the correct order from 1 to 100 sequentially and it takes about 12 seconds.

If i hit Ctrl+F5, the load time decreases a lot and the elements will be printed in seemingly random order and it just takes about 1 second.

I thought that Ctrl+F5 would mean "Load everything from the source instead of using the local cache" but it seems that the ajax requests are handled in a different way too. The elements will be printed depending on the answer time of the api server.

Here the difference as images:

[Ctrl + F5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud4kX.png)

[F5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QOXI.png)

How come?

Comment: The AJAX requests will finish whenever they finish. There's variance in transmission time and server processing time, so they won't come back in the same order they were sent. When loading from the cache, there is no network transition or server involvement, so they can complete in the order that they are sent.

Comment: so loading from cache is 12x slower then not loading from cache?

Comment: Just testet this in Firefox and Edge (not Chromium Edge) and there it is always like pressing Ctrl+F5 in Chrome. Its always in random order and loads in ~1 second. So this seems to be some Chrome (or Chromium) speciality...

Comment: Also it appears to behave this way since Chrome Version 75. In Version 74 the behaviour was as it is in Version 75 with cache disabled...